# How do I make some part of words in list bullet bold by python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Now I have a list called `k = ['aaa bbb', 'ccc ddd', 'eee fff']`.
I would like to write list k into a `word file` by `list bullet`, and I want `aaa bbb` (k[0]) be bold in word file. The rest of other element in k is normal.

In other word, I would like it display like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jInIs.jpg)
However, no matter how I try, the result shows no element is bold.

Besides, is it possible to make only `aaa` be bold.
Just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY87U.jpg)

I have tried the function like "bold", "font", "styles".
But they don't work.

```
    document = Document()

    k = ['aaa bbb', 'ccc ddd', 'eee fff']

    for i in range(len(k)):

    if i ==1:
        run = document.add_paragraph(k[i], style = "List Bullet")
        run.bold = True

    else:
        run = document.add_paragraph(k[i], style = "List Bullet")
```

The result is not what I expected. 
After running, there are no bold characters.

Comment: You need 'aaa' to be bold (so just the first word of your element in list) or 'aaa bbb something_more' (so all the element)?

Comment: I want 'aaa'(first word of my element) to be bold eventually. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `add_paragraph` return a Paragraph reference, not a Run.

I found however more convenient to just create an empty bullet list and then `add_run(string)`, setting everytime `bold = True`.

If we change also the logic of parsing lines (with `enumerate` to get also index of current line into your `k` list) we can setup two boolean variables, `make_only_first_word_bold` and `make_only_first_line_bold`.

With the first, we specify that only the first word of a line has to be bolded, while with the second we specify if only the first line of the list has to be bolded or not.

This leads us to four different combinations: nothing bolded, all bolded, all first words bolded and just first word of first line bolded.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
k = ['aaa bbb', 'ccc ddd', 'eee fff']

make_only_first_word_bold = True
make_only_first_line_bold = True

for idx, line in enumerate(k):
    if make_only_first_word_bold:
        words = line.split(maxsplit=1)  # ['aaa', 'bbb even_more_things']
        word_to_bold = words[0] + ' '
        leftover = words[1]
    else:
        word_to_bold = line
        leftover = None

    if make_only_first_line_bold and idx > 0:
        word_to_bold = None
        leftover = line

    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(style='List Bullet')
    if word_to_bold:
        paragraph.add_run(word_to_bold).bold = True
    if leftover:
        paragraph.add_run(leftover)

document.save('test.docx')
```